# How to draw a curve projection?

Tags: plotting, code-request, projection

I want to draw the following projection picture for the cuspidal cubic curve in Mathematica. Does anybody know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: `ContourPlot[y^2 == x^3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`

Comment: Thank you, but I want to add the projection part(down arrow and the bottom line) as well. Your answer only gives the curve part.

Comment: What information can you get from the bottom line? As I see it, it provides no information about the function.

Comment: @azerbajdzan It denotes the projection onto  x-axis, and the dashed line is the singilarity of the function  at the origin. That's why I would like to keep them.

Comment: I see no projection. I see line from left to right without any difference between region on the left of the zero and right of the zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mainly because I wanted to figure out the Bezier curve, having just given another Bezier answer. After doing it, I thought, Why not share?, even though this sort of plain Graphics is what I learned to do back around 1990 and was still doing when I found this community. Others may benefit from looking up `Text[]` for any annotations to be added (be sure to check out `` MaTeX` ``  too) as well as styling directives like `Thickness` and colors.

```
Block[{t = 0.9, x, y, pts},
 x = t^2; y = t^3;
 pts = {{x, -y}, {-1/3 x, y}, {-1/3 x, -y}, {x, y}};
 Graphics[{
   White, EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[-{x, x}, {x, x}]
   , Black, BezierCurve[pts]
   , {Dashed, Black, Line[{{0, x}, {0, -1.6 x}}]}
   , {Black, Line[{{-x, -1.6 x}, {t^2, -1.6 x}}], 
    Line[{{0, -1.56 x}, {0, -1.64 x}}], 
    Arrow[{{0.1 x, -1.1 x}, {0.1 x, -1.5 x}}]}
   }]
 ]
```

[image]

*Note: On my Front End, there seems to be a bug (`"14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"`). Depending on the image size of the graph, the cusp is sometimes not rendered. The export seems to work, though.*

Answer (score 4):

```
fu = y^2 == x^3;
xrange = {-2, 2};
lines = Select[
   FunctionDomain[SolveValues[fu, y], x] /. 
     Inequality | GreaterEqual | LessEqual | Greater | Less | Or -> 
      List // Flatten, NumericQ];

GraphicsColumn[{ContourPlot[
     Evaluate@fu, {x, Splice@xrange}, {y, -3, 3}, 
     Epilog -> {Dashed, InfiniteLine[{{#, 0}, {#, 1}}] & /@ lines}, 
     FrameLabel -> {{"", ""}, {"", fu}}], 
    Graphics[{ColorData[97, 1], AbsoluteThickness[1.6`], 
      MeshPrimitives[
       Region[ImplicitRegion[
          LogicalExpand[
           FunctionDomain[SolveValues[#, y], x] && y == 0.05], {x, 
           y}], PlotRange -> {xrange, {-0.1, 0.1}}] // 
        DiscretizeRegion, 1]}, PlotRange -> {xrange, {-0.1, 0.1}}, 
     Axes -> {True, False}]}] &@fu
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I see you have added more examples which is great!